# Resized uploaded photos in CodeIgniter-based website

Tags: codeigniter, upload, controller, image-resizing, image-uploading

OK so this is proving a mystery so I thought in desperation I would throw it out there to see if anyone else has had a similar thing going on. One of our (CodeIgniter-based) pages has a photo upload function. This is merrily uploaded to **upload/orig** and resized somewhere and put in **upload/thumb**.

I have checked the page code itself to find the parameters for this resize and they are not in the file. I have checked ALL controller files and although there are a couple of resize functions going on I have changed their directory names to test whether they are indeed the right functions for the original problem... they are not! I have then searched all files for references to the size, the function name, resize as a search-term and file_up as a search term... and nothing.

The resize is **602 x 340px**

Does anyone have any idea what I could have missed? I really don't want these photos being resized.

Comment: I'd check the config files to see if there is anything in there. Some developers create a config array for initialization so they don't have to do it in their controllers.

Comment: Also check all the libraries used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Joe, you are simply going to have to properly trace your code.
I would identify the FORM that is being submitted, then work through the controller and the method that handles the upload.

Typically your resize happens upon upload (in most cases).

Your question is really not something we could answer, as we don't see your code.  We can only give you vague answers that may or not be relevant.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, yes I know it's very specific... I just hoped somebody else was in a similar position. It's really odd. My next stop is the models files.

Comment: @JoeW, I doubt you would have resize data in models, that would really be a terrible place for it, and if whoever put it there should be shot ;)

Comment: Good right, ok, that is that option eliminated then! I will continue to investigate and pull what's left of my hair out.